# Android firebase query with multiple orderBy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrive all data in my firebase database which genre has "Gospel"

Here's my database:

[image]

```
DatabaseReference infoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().geReference().child("info");

infoRef.orderByChild("genre").orderByValue().equalTo("Gospel").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
     log.i("data", dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
```

I need other query because multiple orderBy is invalid.

Thanks...

Comment: You can only order by/filter on one property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. But once you filter on the genre, you can re-order the data client-side.

Comment: One more solution is that, given the fact an album belongs to a single genre, you could structure the data as genre : "Gospel" and use a orderByChild("genre").equalTo("Gospel") to get the parent node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple orderBy are not allowed in Firebase

Try this

```
infoRef.orderByChild("genre").equalTo("Gospel").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
 log.i("data", dataSnapshot.toString());
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

}
});
```